# Proof that four values have to be rational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Following is defined:

$$z=\frac{cx+dy}{ax+by}$$

I have these four terms:

$$v_1=b+az$$
$$v_2=a-bz$$
$$v_3=d+cz$$
$$v_4=c-dz$$

---

The requirements are: $x,y\in\mathbb{Z};v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\in\mathbb{Q}$. Meaning that x & y are whole numbers and the four terms are all rational.

---

*From these conditions I want to **prove that a, b, c, and d have to be rational**. This might not be true and if so I would like to see a counter example or proof that falsifies the claim and I would really like to know the restrictions on a, b, c, and d that these four terms give rise to. Can they be all real numbers or only specific ones etc.*

---

I have already tried to algebraically manipulate the term to find a more suitable shape but have not succeeded.

$$a-b\frac{cx+dy}{ax+by}=\frac{\frac{a^2}bx+ay-cx-dy}{\frac a b x+y}$$

I have also tried to go about it by considering the general rules for adding and multiplying  rational and irrational numbers, like rational * irrational = irrational and such. But this also did not seem to get me anywhere.

Additionally I tried to divide the problem into many multiple cases depending on if a, b, or z were rational or not and could show this claim for the case that z is rational. But ultimately this wasn't an answer either.

Comment: Where does it come from?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti I am currently working on my first mathematical "paper" (it's kinda like a high school dissertation). I got to a point where I wanted to find all the parallelogram grids where squares can be put on the grid points. The a, b, c, and d are the values for the transformation matrix (which is a linear transformation of the square grid). x and y are the original coordinates of one of the corners of the square before the transformation which therefore have to be integers. I have to show the claim in order to be able to prove my theory for which grids squares can lie on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample follows:
$$x=0; \qquad y=1; \qquad a= \sqrt2 + 1; \qquad b=1; \qquad c=-3-2\sqrt2; \qquad  d=\sqrt2 -  1 $$

This counterexample was built with the idea of simplifying computations. If you put $(x;y;b)=(0;1;1)$, then the expression for $z$ becomes simply $$z=d$$

I noticed that $a,b,c,d$ are all rational if and only if $z$ is rational. Hence I picked (cleverly) an irrational $d$ and built the counterexample.

I leave you the details, in particular you can check on your own that these values indeed provide a counterexample.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted. Good job!

Comment: I also don't know who downvoted. I just checked the counter example. It indeed is true. Thank you very much for providing me with this information. I previously thought that maybe all four numbers have to be of the form: $p + kq$ for some rational numbers p and q and an irrational number k. This still might be the restriction I am looking for but isn't technically part of my original question. In this case it might be $k=\sqrt2$. I probably have to open a new thread for this one or just try to figure it out first.

Comment: I didn't check the following: maybe $k= \sqrt{ \mathrm{anything \ rational}}$ would provide other counterexamples. I toook $\sqrt 2$ just for sake of simplicity

Comment: @Crostul Yes, I mean maybe all the four numbers a, b, c, and d always have to have the same value of k in the form of $p+kq$ for a single example. And that for your counter example it happened to be $k=\sqrt2$ (and the p and q values: $p_a=1,q_a=1,p_b=1,q_b=0,p_c=-3,q_c=-2,p_d=-1,q_d=1$). Maybe all values of $k\in\mathbb R$ could lead to counter examples. I just have to figure out if this restriction is true. I'll wait a bit if someone can confirm this and then accept yours as the accepted answer. I'll maybe open another question for that later if nobody knows. Thank you very much nonetheless!

Comment: And also I think the thing you noticed might not be true. If a, b, c, and d are numbers of the form $p_i*k$ for some rational number p and the same irrational number k, they are all irrational but z isn't. For example: $a=\sqrt2,b=2\sqrt2,c=3\sqrt2,d=4\sqrt2$. They are irrational but $z=\frac{\sqrt2(3x+4y)}{\sqrt2(x+2y)}=\frac{3x+4y}{x+2y}$. This is definitely rational.